# ESM Error Occurs ONLY on Sever (Not in Development)

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I have a Node/Express application that I start with: `node -r esm index.js` (ie. I'm using the `esm` package to enable `import` syntax in my app).

In my dev environment, my app starts up great.  However, on my AWS (Ubuntu) server ... with the exact same code, and the exact same Node version (16.16.0) I get the error:

```
/home/ubuntu/project/admin/server/index.js:1
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/ubuntu/project/admin/server/node_modules/lodash-es/lodash.js not supported.
Instead change the require of lodash.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/project/admin/server/index.js:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

From what I can tell this is some kind of `require` vs. `import` issue, but what I can't understand is why I would have such an issue *only on my server*.

Can anyone explain how this could be possible?  I can't think of any environmental factor that could be responsible, other than Node itself (which again is at the same version).

Comment: How did you installed the dependencies on the prod system?

Comment: What build and deploy chain do you use? It looks as if something is transpiling your code before putting it on the server.

Comment: I install dependencies wiih `npm install`, and there's no build/deploy chain.  I'm just git cloning the same repo that works in dev up to my AWS instance, running `npm i`, and then running `npm start` (which runs `node -r esm index.js`).

Comment: Why are you not using native modules instead of `esm`?

Comment: Because I started the project prior to official ES  Module support.  One possible fix for this issue is to stop using `esm`, but A) that's work I'd rather avoid; the last time I tried it it was *not* as simple as just removing `-r esm` and adding that module line to `package.json` ... and B) I'm genuinely curious as to ho how this issue is happening, and just want to understand it out of curiosity

Comment: Are there any config files, environment variables, hidden files etc on your local machine that are not checked into git, but that do affect either `node` or `esm`?

Comment: Good thought, but there's just dot-env, and environmental vars are only relevant once the app starts; I don't think they could have any effect on `esm`